# Can't change state of other Ttk Checkbutton using command- Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

[Output *after some changes](https://m.imgur.com/a/0wG48D1)

How do i make one CheckButton get disabled and checked, when any other CheckButton is clicked.

I want to disable as well set `chk1` to Checked upon hitting `chk2` as Checked and if Unchecked i want `chk1`'s state to be set as normal.

I get an error using below-

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        var1 = tk.IntVar()
        chk1 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text = 'Class', variable = var1)
        #chk1.state(['selected'])
        chk1.pack(side = 'left')
        var2 = tk.IntVar()
        chk2 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text = 'Section', variable = var2,
        command = lambda: self.chk(chk1, var2))
        #chk2.state(['selected'])
        chk2.pack(side = 'left')

    def chk(self, obj, self_val):
        if self_val.get() == 1: #changed from 0 to 1
            obj.state['selected']
            obj.configure(state = 'disabled')
        else:
            obj.configure(state = 'normal')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Root().mainloop()
```

```sh
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sagar\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\chkbtn.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    command = lambda: self.chk(chk1, var2))
  File "d:\chkbtn.py", line 24, in chk
    obj.state['selected']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why are you using a lambda to pass the variables when you could use a class attribute instead? Also change `obj.state['selected']` to `obj.state(['selected'])` in your method.

Comment: Uhhhh, i had right the first time but i accidentally typed in state without braces while defining the function, but the problem isn't solved yet, it's isn't functioning as i intended for it to work. Also if i don't use lambda then chk1 is always disabled. Don't know why?

Comment: All right,  the problem is somewhat fixed by changing the value in if statement from 0 to 1 but, when chk1 is disabled and chk2 is clicked then chk1 is disabled as intended but not showing checked, why?

Comment: Well you error is solved correct? And the code works as expected on my end by fixing the one thing I mentioned.

Comment: Look my comment above about the problem i have now.

Comment: The problem you had with your original error is fixed correct? If that is the case and you have a new problem then you need to ask a new question.

Comment: It's still the same question though, the thing is chk1 gets disabled but not checked when chk2 is clicked. I.e, ```obj.state(['selected'])``` have no effect. And that's what I'm asking in the question as to how to satisfy both condition.

Comment: I think you need more context to your question then. From the correction to get rid of your error and the change you made to `==  1` the code works as described in your question. Maybe add some screen shots of your issue.

Comment: How do i explain this more then, i can't even post pics to elaborate better.

Comment: Ok then go post screen shots on another image host site and then provide links. I will edit your post then to include the images for clarity.

Comment: Do you know any image host site to get pics posted quickly.

Comment: Ok I just updated my answer I think you wanted to also uncheck `chk1` after its status is set back to normal.

Comment: https://imgur.com/upload works well here.

Comment: Adding problem's output anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after some confusion you need to add a 3rd variable to your lambda and method.

In order to set the state and to update the variable.

Try the below and let me know if that helps:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        var1 = tk.IntVar(self)
        var2 = tk.IntVar(self)
        chk1 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text='chk1', variable=var1)
        chk2 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text='chk2', variable=var2, command=lambda: self.chk(var1, chk1, var2))
        chk1.pack(side='left')
        chk2.pack(side='left')

    def chk(self, var1, chk1, chk2):
        if chk2.get() == 1:
            var1.set(1) # need to set the value of var1 to update chk1
            chk1.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            var1.set(0)
            chk1.configure(state='normal')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Root().mainloop()
```

Here is an example using class attributes instead of a lambda.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var1 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.var2 = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.chk1 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text='chk1', variable=self.var1)
        chk2 = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text='chk2', variable=self.var2, command=self.chk)
        self.chk1.pack(side='left')
        chk2.pack(side='left')

    def chk(self):
        if self.var2.get() == 1:
            self.var1.set(1)  # need to set the value of var1 to update chk1
            self.chk1.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            self.var1.set(0)
            self.chk1.configure(state='normal')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Root().mainloop()
```

Comment: Work perfectly now, but why didn't ```obj.set(['selected'])``` worked? Also you said not to use lambda but if not the program doesn't work properly, why's that?

Comment: @Sagar I said you can use class attributes. Currently your variables are not set as attributes.

Comment: Oh,  that makes sense. Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: @Sagar to answer your question about `obj.set()` Tkinters CheckButton does not have a `set()` That said if you meant `obj.state(['selected'])` then that is likely due to the state only being able to be set to 3 options. `normal`, `disabled` and `active`. My guess is that it just ignored the command. Though I would think it would throw an error.